# How can i resize complex icons in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have the next code for several icons in google maps but does not work when a try to resize serval icons.

I need help because my icons are diferents size

```
           var iconBase = '../../Content/images/';
            var icons = {
                WIND: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'turbin.gif',
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, -15),
                    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 80),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 80)
                },
                OTHER: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
                },

                SOLAR: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'panel.gif'
                },

            };
```

Comment: If you want the size to scale, `scaledSize` and `size` need to be different.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon), `icon` below should be `url`:

```
WIND: {
    icon: iconBase + 'turbin.gif',
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, -15),
    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 80),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 80)
}
```

should be:

```
WIND: {
    url: iconBase + 'turbin.gif',
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, -15),
    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 80),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 80)
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5kh55fwb/)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (in your question).